# Php object return null value while echo is working

Tags: php, object, null

i took a class and function and determine size of file.but when i echo the size and call the function it works but when i store it in variable and call via object it shows null value,whats wrong can be there?
when i use

```
echo $currentsize;
```

it gives me value but object does not store any thing.

```
<?php
class Mainc {

public $sizenow;        

function myprocess(){    
    $currentsize= 1.20;
    echo $currentsize;
    $this->size = $currentsize;
 }
}

$objsize=new Mainc();
var_dump($objsize);
```

Comment: Do you call the method `smprocess()` somewhere?

Comment: forget to add main thing..............

Answer (score 2):

Your `$sizenow` is not initialized unless you call `smprocess()` which your example code does not do. Alter it to:

```
$objsize=new Mainc();
$objsize->smprocess();
var_dump($objsize);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems I see in your code. First is that you are not called smprocess() method. Also you are using   $this->size_now and the property is defined public $sizenow;

I believe this will fix your code